# Phonegap getting content from a PDF file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to get a content from a pdf file using phonegap(android). is that possible? I have been searching about "how to get content from a pdf file using javascript" but i think it might be better to specify what tool I'm working with.

My objective is to search a `Content` in a PDF(String/Word) and display it. My idea is to open the PDF file and extract its content to a variable but the problem there is the memory, i think the variable can't support a large content of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i Think You can use the power of HTML-5 ,ie use  HTML 5  FileReader API . i think it is possible

[Check this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)